# Hot reload not updating asset files

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter for almost a year. And one thing that I don't really understand or can't find an answer for it.

I started the application. Then I added some assets to the specified by `pubspec.yaml` file.

Now I know that I need to run `pub get`. But when I run `hot reload` or `hot restart` there's no update (App don't have new Images). Asset files are allowed to use when I stop the app and `start` again.

Be sure to let me know if any articles can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the difference is: 
**Hot reload:** just reload the UI, it rebuilds the UI(user interface), without losing the state of your app(variables content, etc).
**Hot Restart:** loads code changes, and restarts the Flutter app, but basically it uses the precompile files to save time instead reloading the whole app.
So you have to stop the app when you change something in your pubspec or for example in your andriodManifest because this files are updated just when you compile again your app..

Comment: Can you please suggest to me some idea? I'm working on a bunch of JSON files.

Comment: suggest about what? In what are you working? you can describe me a little bit more your idea and I will give you some suggest if I have!

Comment: I am sorry. I was wrong. When I modify a JSON file, it automatically changes its data.